# MPLAB X IDE v2.30　ライブラリ追加方法について

Tags: c

現在、`dspic33fj128mc202` 上で動かすプログラムをタイトルに表記した IDE にて開発しています。(OS は Windows7 です)

DSP ライブラリを使用するため、以下のファイルを

```
C:/Program Files/Microchip/xc16/v1.24/lib/dsPIC33F/libp33FJ128MC202-coff.a
```

プロジェクト直下の　`Libraries`　フォルダに追加して、以下の include 文をソースコードに追加しました。

```
#include <dsp.h>
```

そして、ライブラリ関数である　`VectorCopy`　を使用するソースコードをビルドしたところ、以下のエラーメッセージが表示されてビルドに失敗してしまいます。

> ```
> build/default/production/data.o(.text+0xcc):In function '.LSM14':
> :undefined reference to '_VectorCopy'
> ```

参考にしたテキストが古いため、最新の IDE で DSP ライブラリの追加・使用方法をご存知の方、ご教授いただければ幸いです。

Comment: MPLAB X IDE ユーザガイドには `4.11 ライブラリ等のファイルのプロジェクトへの追加` という項目がありますが、その項目に書かれている設定は行いましたか？